# General (dis)advantages of ways to define new commands

Tags: macros, expl3, best-practices, documentclass-writing, primitives

I have a question about the many ways to define a new command.
I looked through the web and TeX.SE but couldn't find a complete answer (only some partly answers like, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97657/which-commands-exist-to-define-new-commands), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220692/preferred-way-to-define-a-text-command-with-or-without-a-parameter), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512860/is-there-a-general-format-for-latex-commands), or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655/what-is-the-difference-between-def-and-newcommand)).

I know of several ways:

- `\newcommand`,
- `\DeclareRobustCommand`,
- `\newrobustcmd`,
- `\NewDocumentCommand`,
- `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`

to name just a few, most of them also with starred versions, and of course the primitives like

- `\def`,
- `\gdef`,
- `\edef` and so on.

I have come to the conclusion that it is usually better to use LaTeX macros to define new commands, rather than using primitives. Some arguments pro macros are better syntax (allowing you to understand the execution), security (since most macros check for existing command-names), or the possibility to patch or redefine the commands.

But when I skimmed through several other **cls** files by third parties, I found that they very often use the `\def` primitives over the elaborated macros. The latter are more or less only used in special situations.

Are there valid reasons to use primitives over LaTeX macros to define new commands; **especially** when writing a **cls** file? Maybe reduce package size, or something similar? Or just old habits?

I know that it will depend on the situation, if I simply use `\newcommand` or `\newrobustcmd`. But maybe there is a strong tendency, when to use primitives in class files rather than macros?

**Edit**

As suggested in my question and confirmed in the comments there is no general answer. Therefore, it would be great if some of the more **experienced LaTeX authors** could share their **personal preferences** when **writing/editing a class file**, and why they do it this way.

**Edit 2**

What I forgot so far are the `expl3` commands like `\cs_new...`. If I understood it correctly, **LaTeX3** was introduced as elaborated programming layer especially for usage in **sty**, **cls** and other backend files. So, would/should a modern approach in writing such files relay more on these `expl3` commands than on primitives or more or less simple LaTeX macros?

Comment: For frontend macros: There is no good reason if you only target LaTeX to use primitives for the definitions. But for internal parsing stuff, there are things that are only really possible with primitives, for instance right delimited arguments. But if you want to play safe, you can wrap your primitve definitions in `\@ifdefinable`.

Comment: But that internal parsing stuff seems not to be used all the time. Nevertheless, `\def` is used very often, also for very simple definitions like `\def\command{short definition}`. That's one of the points why I ask if there is a reason for that frequent use of it. But maybe its all due to my little experience working in the Latex *backend*...

Comment: I suspect the answer to your questions is "all of the above". The range of technical skill of package/class writers varies substantially, and code gets copied over the years. So there's probably a lot of inconsistency overall. But for internal commands there's no real need for the overhead of the LaTeX versions which is probably why they get used a lot.

Comment: Class files were introduced with LaTeX2e, which was first released in 1994.  At this time most of the mentioned commands weren't available.  And for former LaTeX2.09 style file authors it was completely normal to use TeX primitives or a mixture of higher level LaTeX commands and TeX primitives.  Nowadays LaTeX has more capabilities, official commands, and hooks to adapt behaviour and layout. Therefore it is better to use newer class files as example.

Comment: @BerndRaichle, maybe I didn't make it clear enough. Of course I mean relatively new class files which nevertheless contain many primitives. I understand That standard class files, like *article* etc., still have many primitives due to historical reasons .

Comment: One reason of still use  primitives as `\def` could be that if you know what are really you doing , why the hell should you deprive yourself of using   `\def` to use, for example, `\newcommand\foo{}`,  and  check if the command was already defined , when that doesn't matter to you?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. So far the fact that there is no general answer is confirmed. I'm curious hearing a personal experience/preference if someone want to tell his/her in an answer :)

Comment: See also [Differences between \newcommand, \NewDocumentCommand and \DeclareRobustCommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/619849/110998)

Comment: @gernot, thanks for one of the many links I may have missed to put in my question. But that's just a definition of the different command types. My question is more about the *use case* of those types (or `expl3` versions) over primitives for class (or package) writing.